# Will Firestore keep reading documents for an onSnapshot listener if the user closes the browser?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I start reading documents from a Firestore collection using a `query.onSnapshot()` call, under what circumstances does Firestore automatically unsubscribe and stop reading docs?

Specifically, if the user closes the browser, or his computer crashes, what happens then? I presume that at some point Firestore will understand that the user is no longer there to receive the data, but how does that work?

I'm creating a PWA, so aside from the browser closing, my user might navigate 'within' the app. Do I have to make sure I meticulously unsubscribe from all open listeners or risk reading unused docs? Or is there some clever mechanism at work to 'garbage collect' abandoned onSnapshot listeners?

Since there is money involved, I'd like to know the specifics of all this. I'd rather avoid paying for document reads that I didn't need anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since web page code can't run after a tab is closed, the listener will be stopped at that time.  The query isn't managed by something persistent like a service worker.

That said, it's *never* a bad idea to be explicit about when to stop listening.  I would consider that a best practice.  Leaving listeners active for longer than anticipated is a good way to get billed more than you'd expect.

Comment: If FireStore used a pull-based method where my code polled for new updates, I wouldn't worry about this. But isn't this set up with listeners and FireStore pushes changes to me. How does Firestore know not to read documents anymore if I don't explicitly unsubscribe? After all, the order of events must be 'read-push', so if there is no explicit unsubscribe from my side, how will Firestore know to not read anymore?

Comment: Firestore doesn't have to "know" anything.  Its execution context is shut down by the browser when the tab closes.  It simply can not run after that, for whatever work you set up in that tab, because the browser doesn't allow work to "leak" outside of the tab.

Comment: I know that my code won't run after the browser is shut down. But it isn't code running in the client browser that is checking for updates on the firestore database. It isn't initiating that traffic using a polling system. Rather, there must be some kind of socket open so that firestore can initiate the action when it detects changes to the database. My question is how firestore knows to stop reading changed documents if 'my side of the socket' goes dark.

Comment: No, it's not running.  None of the code from the page that was closed is running.  The socket is closed and there are no more updates.